# How to view cross validated resample data in r?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, tidymodels

I am new to `tidymodels` & fairly new to R as well.

I created a **recipe** using `tidymodels` which worked well on **train data** but is giving an **error** on **cross validated resamples**.

So I would like to view the resamples but they are not in simple df format.

```
train_5fold

############ result ###########

splits              id
<list>              <chr>

<S3: vfold_split>   Fold1           
<S3: vfold_split>   Fold2           
<S3: vfold_split>   Fold3           
<S3: vfold_split>   Fold4           
<S3: vfold_split>   Fold5
```

**download data**

https://github.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/blob/main/train_5fold.RDS

```
train_5fold <- readRDS("train_5fold.RDS")
```

How can I view them ??

I have tried **pluck(), unnest_wider, unlist** etc but not been able to get the real data frame.

I have also posted another **SO** post on **tidymodels** which remains unanswered till now so trying to debug by cross checking **CV** data

[Getting error when trying to apply tidymodels recipe from train data to resamples in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68407834/getting-error-when-trying-to-apply-tidymodels-recipe-from-train-data-to-resample)

Comment: @RonakShah if you download it manually from the git link then it is working perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the data from each `splits` with `lapply` as -

```
df <- readRDS('train_5fold.RDS')
list_df <- lapply(df$splits, `[[`, 'data')
```

If you want to combine them in one dataframe use `res <- do.call(rbind, list_df)` Or with `purrr` -

```
library(purrr)
res <- map_df(df$splits, pluck, 'data')
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak was struggling with `tidymodels` from quite a long, hope this will help otherwise I may just quit tidymodels & move to `caret` all together to save time & forget tidymodel as I don't find much community support for `tidymodels`